# unsigned integer and integer pointer in c

Tags: c, type-conversion, c-strings, unsigned-integer, atoi

I have a code where I pass 300000(value of 5 min in ms)
in function.

```
            BOOL setsomethingfunc(tpUINT8 value) //tpUINT8 is integer pointer
            {
               bufVal=atoi(value); //bufVal is type UINT8
            }
```

Now when I print bufVal it comes as 224. I'm not able to understand how the value conversion happened. Can someone please explain ?
So, Integer pointer has - 300000 and when converted to int it becomes 224.

I've worked on a minimal reproducible example for the scenrio -

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <stdint.h>

            int main()
            {
                uint8_t backoff;
                char* value = "300000";
                backoff=atoi(value);
                printf("value = %s\n", value);
                printf("backoff value = %d\n", backoff);

                return (0);
            }
```

Output is as -

```
            value = 300000
            backoff value = 224
```

Can someone please help me understand how this conversion happened ?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. If you don't want to spend time in doing it, nobody will want to spend time on your question.

Comment: Neither `tBOOL` nor `tpUINT8` are standard types. We can *guess* what they are, but you better tell us.

Comment: UINT8 can taken same as unit8_t. From what I know size of both char and unit8_t is same, so passing the char type in function is working. But I'm not sure if it changes anything in value.

Comment: value is UINT8, but atoi needs a pointer.

Comment: Don't mix types for no good reason, even if they are aliases for the same thing.  For strings you should use `char*`  and `char` arrays throughout.

Comment: You ***really*** need to provide us with a [mcve]. What is *really* stored in `buf`? *How* do you put that there? With a good example you should initialize `buf` to a hard-coded values (as in `char buf[2000] = "300000";`).

Comment: Also note that is `buf` really contains the string `"300000"`, then your second and third call to `strtok` should return `NULL`, which you then pass of to `setsomethingfunc` and `atoi`. It should on most systems result in a *crash*, not other values. So indeed, we really need a [mcve] because it's impossible to debug your program.

Comment: I've added a minimal reproducible example and edited the question further to point out the problem I'm unable to understand. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `BOOL setsomethingfunc(UINT8 value)` your function should take pointer not the integer. It has to be `BOOL setsomethingfunc(UINT8 *value)`
2. Use standard C types. `uint8_t` for 8 bits unsigned integer and `bool` from `stdbool.h`. Many old code (or the code which development started long time ago like Linix kernel) use those non standard types for historical reasons. You should learn the modern C

Comment: If representing a string, `char*` would be appropriate.

Comment: Annoyingly, there are a lot of tools that `#define UINT8 uint8_t`. Sticking to the types defined in the standard improves readability, maintainability, etc....

Comment: Edited the question as per your remarks, found that I missed an integer pointer here.